# What is formula to calculate “In 5 years” amount on page 3 of the mortgage Loan Estimate form?

Tags: mortgage, loans, home-loan

Loan Estimate form for mortgages in US have a "In 5 years" amount paid. What is the formula for calculating that based on other values in the form ?

On page 3 of the example form at  http://www.consumerfinance.gov/owning-a-home/loan-estimate/ the value is  56582. However, it seems like it should be mortgage payments over 60 months + closing costs - credit. Ie (761.78+82)*60+5672=56299

Context: The loan estimate that I got with lower closing costs after credits has a higher  "In 5 years" and APR compared to another one with same interest rate. Something seems wrong. This led me to try and find the right formula.

Comment: Same interest rate at how many points and what closing costs? APR reflects real cost of the loan including those additional costs.

Comment: Do the credits get accounted for in APR and "In 5 years" number ? What about taxes ? What about "Other costs" section ?

Comment: I'm confused. I thought I was searching that comment to an answer which referenced my previous comment, neither of which I now see. Maybe the Android app has tried it's like wee brain again..